JDBC connection in a python lambda program using py4j
I am trying to use JDBC connection in a python Lambda function. I uploaded the py4j zip as a layer for this Lambda function. I did import py4j. It says No module named py4j. MY program is to test the JDBC connection. No need to do any SQL queries.
import py4j
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

How to fix this error No module named py4j?

Py4J requires a JVM running a gateway server. Do you have one running in your Lambda?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I fixed this issue adding subdirectories in the zip file. Followed this link.
AWS error from Python: No module named lambda_function
